# Generic filter function without knowing key (s)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to make a generic javascript method that filters a list without knowing the key (s).

This is how far i have gotten, and i don't know how to continue. I know this foreach code isn't correct, but i wrote it like this so you could easier understand what i am trying to do.

Someone who can help?

```
filterList(): void {
    let searchtext = this.state.currentSearchBoxValue;
    let searchProperties = this.state.searchBoxOptions.searchProperties;

    let list = this.props.list;

    if(searchtext != undefined && searchtext != '' && searchtext != null) 
    {
        let keys = Object.keys(list[0]);

        searchProperties.forEach(key => {
            list.filter(item => item[key].includes(searchtext));
        })
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could revise your filtering logic, so that the callback passed to `filter()` on your `list` array wraps iteration of `searchProperties` as detailed below:

```
filterList(): void {
    let searchtext = this.state.currentSearchBoxValue;
    let searchProperties = this.state.searchBoxOptions.searchProperties;

    let list = this.props.list;

    if(searchtext != undefined && searchtext != '' && searchtext != null) 
    {    
        /* Call filter to filter items that match search criteria */
        const filteredList = list.filter(item => {

            /* Search for any property where the some() criteria is true for 
               current item */
            return searchProperties.some(searchProperty => {

                /* If item value on current searchProperty key includes searchText, 
                   return true. This means some() will return true, and
                   the "item" will be included in filteredList */
                const itemPropertyValue = item[ searchProperty ];

                return itemPropertyValue.includes(searchtext);
            });
        });

        /* Filtered result */
        console.log(filteredList);
    }     
}
```

As shown above, this solution uses the [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method on the `searchProperties` array which returns `true` if the callback function passed to `some()` returns true for any item in the `searchProperties` array.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly well :)

Comment: Posted a new issue below here. Would appreciate it if you would have time to help me with another filterproblem :)

Comment: @OJs glad I could help :-) yes not a problem - if you would like to give me a link to your next question I will be happy to help on that as well

Comment: Thanks, but found out right after i posted, so i just deleted the post :)